# How to pass dataset directory in google datalab

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-datalab

I have setup google datalab on my local machine then tried to read dataset using pandas by passing custom data directory but it doesn't take path correctly it adds root at the start then try to pass absolute path then it gives error file doesn't exist but file is in the directory.

Can any one help me what is the issue or anyone explain me is there any predefined rule to put the dataset

Answer (score 1):

If you ran Datalab as a docker container on your local machine, it automatically maps your home directory to `/content` inside the container, so just make sure your Dataset is accessible from your home path.

Comment: I have putting dataset in home path only but it doesn't take that

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you provide the steps you made?